# Find a smallest value of the expression ${\frac{1}{3} \; a^{2} - 4 \; a + \frac{3}{4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have an expression

$$\mathbf{\frac{1}{3} \; a^{2} - 4 \; a + \frac{3}{4}}$$

I need to find the smallest value of the expression when $a$ can be any value from interval $\mathbf{ \left(-∞; ∞ \right)}$.

Comment: i can not see an equation

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That is odd. I can see it fine.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{1}{3}a^2-4a+\frac{3}{4}=0$$?

Comment: By that, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner means there is no equals sign. What you have is a function, and you wish to minimize this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}a^2-4a+\frac{3}{4} 
&= 
\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2
-
2\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}\right)(2\sqrt{3})
+
(2\sqrt{3})^2-12+\frac{3}{4}
\\
&
=
\left(
\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}-(2\sqrt{3})
\right)^2
-\frac{48}{4}+\frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
Then the minimum value of the expression $\frac{1}{3}a^2-4a+\frac{3}{4}$ is equal to $-\frac{48}{4}+\frac{3}{4}=-\frac{45}{4}$ and occurs when $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{3}}-2\sqrt{3}=0$, *i.e.* $a=6$.

Answer (score 1):

#### in generally:

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a>0$. Then
$$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\ge c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
And $$ax^2+bx+c=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\Leftrightarrow x=-\frac b{2a}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Answer using calculus** The derivative with respect to $a$ is
$$
\frac{2}{3} a  - 4.
$$
So if you solve $\frac{2}{3} a - 4 = 0$ and plug in the value for $a$ into the original expresion, you will get your answer.

Note, that it is a quadratic function that "opens up", so this point where the derivative is zero will in fact be a minimum (and not a maximum or some other kind of point.)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean a function $$f(a)=\frac{1}{3}a^2-4a+\frac{3}{4}$$ then you will get
$$f'(a)=\frac{2}{3}a-4$$ and $$f''(a)=\frac{2}{3}$$
You must solve the equation $$\frac{2}{3}a-4=0$$